# Encode value of two way binding

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a two way binding with a property on my component.  The purpose is to take a URL from the users and then redirect through to `/report/<url>`.

Problem is that it beaks on the url and re-directs to `report/http%3A` and misses off the domain.

This is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<input type='text' [(ngModel)]='testUrl' />
<button class='btn btn-primary'(click)='checkMobile()'>Check Site</button>
```

Component

```
import { Component }  from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: "check-mobile",
    templateUrl: "app/check-mobile.component.html"
})
export class CheckMobileComponent{
    testUrl: string;

    constructor(private router: Router)
    {

    }

    checkMobile() : void {

        var escapedUrl = encodeURI(this.testUrl);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/report/' + escapedUrl);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: also you are starting from /reports/ and then adding the http after so that will not work. 

does the user input url with http:// etc ?

Comment: i want the encoded value as the path.  For instance `/reports/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [QueryEncoder](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/QueryEncoder-class.html) provided by Angular 2. Do this

```
import { QueryEncoder } from '@angular/http';

var encodedUrl = new QueryEncoder().encodeValue(this.testUrl);
this.router.navigate(['/report/' + escapedUrl]);
```

Comment: This does the exact same thing.  It navigates to `/report/http%3A` and cuts off at the domain

Comment: @Guerrilla can you try now ?

Comment: @Guerrilla what version of angular are you using? the newer versions take an array. But remove the array and just leave the string.

Comment: sorry i deleted last comment, i didn't notice you changed method call also.  using it this way I get error which I think shows issue: `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'report/http%3A/google.com'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'report/http%3A/google.com'` for some reason it is not encoding the forward slashes and it is breaking the route

Comment: if you go to report/http//:google.com by hand you actually get something ?

Comment: actually no which is weird.  If I go to `/report/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com` then I get a `cannot GET`error but if I got to `/report/randomstring` then it works fine.  My path is this: `{ path: 'report/:url', component: MobileReportComponent }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137772/discussion-between-eduardo-dennis-and-guerrilla).